# Explanation for p-value inequality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I was trying to go over this paper by [Dudoit, Shaffer and Boldric](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1056397487) when I came across this statement on page 78 (under section 2.4: Control of family-wise error rate):

$P(P_j\leq x \vert H_j)\leq x,$ for any $x\in[0,1] $

where

$P_j$ are the p-values and $H_j$ are true null hypotheses for $j=1,...,m_0$.

I'm still new in statistics and as simple as the inequality seems, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  Can someone explain this inqeuality in plain words?

In addition, I'm currently doing a project in multiple hypotheses testing correction on dependent variables and it would be helpful if there are any good papers you can recommend that I read.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the inequality is presuming there are $m_0$ tests you want to run, and in every case, the null hypothesis is true. Then the inequality states that for each test, and for any real number $x ∈ [0, 1]$, the chance of getting a $p$-value less than or equal to $x$ is itself $x$. So, for example, the chance of getting $p \leq .05$ is $.05$. This is equivalent to saying that under the null hypothesis, $p$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$, as is typically desired.